# ShareKit + Facebook authentication not working

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, cordova, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit to post to Facebook from a PhoneGap app which I'm working on. I created the app in Facebook and installed the plugin in my project. Twitter works fine, but I get the following error when I try to share on Facebook:

"
Error:
Sorry the application you are using is misconfigured for Facebook integration. Please download the newest version of the application.
"

I've seen a couple posts that seem to describe this same problem, but the "solutions" involve not using ShareKit and instead integrating manually. This isn't a solution!

Has anyone figured this out?

More details:
ShareKit v0.2.1
Xcode: v4.3.1
PhoneGap (aka Cordova) v1.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the original ShareKit from Nate Weiner doesn't get frequently updated. Maybe you should check out [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). I didn't have any problems integrating it in my app. At least Twitter and Facebook where no problems, that's all I use for the moment.

Comment: I'll check it out. It's really frustrating because I just hired someone to write me a phonegap plugin, which uses the other ShareKit... so is totally useless

Comment: As ShareKit 2.0 is originally based on your version of ShareKit you might possibly have luck and the plugin might work as it is... but I guess you know Murphy's Law... Good luck ;)

Answer (score 4):

go to class facebook.m and change the authorization to NO as mention below:

- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions 
  {
  self.permissions = permissions;

  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
  }

Comment: perfect! way better than going to FB application etc

Comment: I don't see facebook.m in my project? i'm using ShareKit 2.1