# ShareKit Unable to Share Message or image to the Facebook

Tags: cordova, sharekit

[image: Error]

I am using share kit to publish image or message to Facebook.After the login page appears The following error was occurring .The error show in image.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This link helped me: [ShareKit + Facebook authentication not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951292/sharekit-facebook-authentication-not-working)
The answer of "Ramel singh Rana" in particular.
Hope this helps others too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.